# Apache Spark | What is the input file formats required by spark MLlib for different statistics algorithms

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm new to Apacha Spark and MLlib. I have got the fair understanding of using the library (MLlib) apart from one thing. I don't understand how do I prepare the input data file for various algorithms. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the examples provided on MLlib page you will be able to find an example which details creation of input data. 
To provide a pointer suppose you have a text csv file in your storage in which the last line is the label. Then the following code will make a labeled point RDD for you which can be submitted to MLlib algorithms.

```
val inputData = trainTextData.map { lines =>
      val parts = lines.split(",")
      LabeledPoint(parts(index).toDouble, Vectors.dense(remove(parts,index).map(x => if(x=="NULL") (0.0).toDouble else x.toDouble).toArray))
    }.cache
```

You can write your maps to create the data from your input using the same way. It will highly depend on your data though.

Comment: As of now, we have a set of input,  we run the given lines of program in the examples and we get some output. By this exercise I don't understand the logical functioning on the given input.

Is there any proper documentation available for MLlib algorithms, like, what does these function calls mean technically, what are the placeholders and labels used in the format we use for an algorithm? 

After the algorithm execution, I get a set of outputs. What does these data points mean? Any reference or any help to make it understandable. Thanks.

Comment: You will need a lot of work to make sense of all of it. Start with MLLIB documentation on SPARK website. Follow tutorials on web which you find.